# How to delete a huge amount of data without increasing CPU on server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to delete a huge amount of data without increasing CPU SQL server.

Here is example of my query. Subquery returns about 999K Rows and I need to delete one by one. But the problem it deletes first thousand  and gives error

```
Msg -2, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

DECLARE @i INT
CREATE TABLE #TempListingTable (ID INT Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1), ListingID INT)
DECLARE @numrows INT
DECLARE @ListingID INT

INSERT #TempListingTable 

SELECT T1.ListingID
FROM Table T1 WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table T2        
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID IS NULL AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL

SET @i = 1
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempListingTable)
IF @numrows > 0
    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #TempListingTable))
    BEGIN

    SET @ListingID = (SELECT ListingID FROM #TempListingTable WHERE ID = @i)    


    DELETE Listing WHERE ListingID = @ListingID

    SET @i = @i + 1

    END
```

If I delete in subquery like you can see below the CPU goes up and gives timeouts

```
DELETE T1
FROM Table T1 WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table T2        
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID IS NULL AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL
```

What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Overheating? Seriously? ...sounds like a hardware problem. Software has no temperature.

Comment: In your second subquery you are joining on T1 to T2, but you aren't using any values in T2 to filter your results...can you just avoid joining T2?  Wouldn't it make the query run faster?

Comment: We just call those timeouts, not overheating.

Comment: I have a feeling the lack of filtering by T2 is a typo.  I mean, `WHERE T1.ID IS NULL AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL`?  Shouldn't select any rows.

Comment: Eugene, why do you need to delete one row at a time?  And why does it need to have a join?

Comment: because I'm getting this error Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. if I try to remove all at once. The join needs to be there because I have two tables, and if values not present in one of them I need to delete from another one

Comment: Try adding BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION around the DELETE inside the loop.  That should ensure that it doesn't try to batch all of the DELETEs in one big transaction.  When I have had to delete a large number of rows, I've generally tried to delete blocks of 100 or so at a time to get reasonable performance without the transaction log getting bent out of shape.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your sql first, it should never delete any rows since T1.ID is null and T1.ID is not null. Fix that and use something like this

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

    DELETE TOP 1000 T1  
    FROM Table T1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table T2          
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID  
    WHERE 1 = 2
    -- replace 'where' statement with a prober wherestatement. 
    -- I assume this is the 'where' statement you want
    --WHERE T2.ID IS NULL 
    --AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK
END
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a .NET timeout, and nothing to do with SQL Server. You don't need to increase the timeout, you need to batch the deletes. If you say it deletes the first thousand and then gives an error, take your script to do the deletes and throw it in a proc that limits the number of records to delete to 1000 by using either TOP 1000 or DELETE TOP(1000), and then have the application fire that proc repeatedly. Have the proc give a return value (0 if there are no more rows to delete, 1 if there are) to control the application firing the proc.

Otherwise, can you elaborate on why you need to delete almost 100K rows one at a time?